# Typescript change object property values dynamically error

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm trying to dynamically change object property values based on the property type, e.g., replace all object string properties with "***". I keep getting `Type '"***"' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'`

I've tried finding the correct way of doing this in Typescript GitHub repository but no luck.

I'm using the latest version of Typescript as of writing this "3.8.2".

Anyone knows what is the correct way of changing object property values when accessing properties dynamically?

Example:

```js
interface IClassA {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const user: IClassA = {
    name: "Jhon Doe",
    age: 20
};

obfuscate(user);

export function obfuscate<T extends IClassA>(obj: T) {
    for (const prop of Reflect.ownKeys(obj) as (keyof T)[]) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "string") {
            obj[prop] = "***";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33391

Comment: using `keyof T` is saying  that the value of `prop` will be `string`, `number`, or `Symbol`, AKA: `obj['number']` and not `obj['name']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why doing this but the simplest (dirty) hack to do this is casting you text to any :

```
if (typeof obj[prop] === "string") {
            obj[prop] = ("***" as any);
}
```